# How to make Angular Scrolling Pagging using http service

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I try to follow one example scrolling pagging using Angular from here
http://akashagrawal.me/blog/2014/01/31/infinite-scroller-in-angularjs/
This is other example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/joshkurz/yaPK7/
my question is , how to make this scrolling pagging using ajax / http request agular for get value from my service.php file and show to web??

and this is my js code

```
// create the module and name it test for testing 
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', []);

routerApp.directive('scroller',function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            loadingMethod : "&"
        },
        link : function(scope,elem,attrs){

            rawElement = elem[0];
            elem.bind('scroll',function(){
                if((rawElement.scrollTop + rawElement.offsetHeight+5) >= rawElement.scrollHeight)
                {
                    scope.$apply(scope.loadingMethod);
                }

            })
        }
    }
});

routerApp.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope)
{
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.counter= 0;
    $scope.dogs = ['tes' , 'Husky' , 'Goldendoogle'];
    $scope.loadMore =  function(){
        i = 1;

    var url = "data.php";
    $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data){
         var items = data;

        console.log(data);

    })

    while(i<10){
      // i want it can push my data not number. how to implemented that?
            $scope.items.push(++$scope.counter);
            i++;

    } 

    };

    $scope.loadMore();
})
```

i think somepeople can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this demo.
You need to create factory/service to send the ajax request. e.g:

```
routerApp.service('thingsService', function($http){
    this.getThings = function(data){
        return $http.get('/things/url, {params : data});
    };
});
```

Then you directive inject this service, and invoke 'getThings' when scroll event is triggered by user.

```
routerApp.directive('scroller',function(){
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function(scope,elem,attrs){

        rawElement = elem[0];
        elem.bind('scroll',function(){
            if((rawElement.scrollTop + rawElement.offsetHeight+5) >= rawElement.scrollHeight)
            {
               scope.$apply('loadMore()');
            }

        })
    }
}; });
```

Your controller:

```
routerApp.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope, thingsService)
{
    var counter= 0;
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.dogs = ['tes' , 'Husky' , 'Goldendoogle'];
    $scope.loadMore = function(){
        //send 'GET' request to your server 
        thingsService.getThings({page: counter}).success(function(data){
            //handle success data here like render the data to view
            $scope.items.push(data);
            counter++;
        }).error(function(){
            //handle http error here
        }); 
        // eg: /things/url?page=0 
    };
    $scope.loadMore();
});
```

So each time the directive listen scroll event, it will trigger the loadMore function in controller. And controller will invoke ThingsService to send a ajax request to your server. 
Hope this can help. : )

Comment: It's ok, it seems you need to inject 'thingsService' into your directive. If still not working, can you post you demo code to jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for your answer..i 've still got some errors when implemented this. the error show me something like this ReferenceError: counter is not defined at Scope.$scope.loadMore .

Comment: i try to write in jsfiddle. It's not working properly . http://jsfiddle.net/009a9gc0/2/

Comment: See the [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/009a9gc0/8/). Change some code, add cors support in jsfiddle. @firman

Comment: Hi it's working . thank u. i can continue from this. Thank's. i update the script in jsfiddle to if you want to see http://jsfiddle.net/009a9gc0/15/

Comment: URI block... Anyway, enjoy it. :  )